# re.search greedy matching all combinations (letters, special characters, numbers)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a pattern using `re.search`

How do I search a url like

```
blah&match=Z-300&
```

and get what comes after `match=`

So in this case, 
I want to get `Z-300`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
s = 'blah&match=Z-300&'
print re.search('&match=(.*)',s).group(1) #Z-300&
print re.search('&match=(.*)&',s).group(1) #Z-300
```

Comment: How can I stop at certain point though? Stop when I see next &

Comment: And sometimes there is no &. It will end after match=Z-300

Comment: May be so: re.search('&match=([^&]*)',s).group(1)

Answer (score 4):

As tends to be my favorite answer to `regex` questions, don't use regex.

Use `urlparse`.  (in py3, `urllib.parse`)

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

parse_qs('blah&match=Z-300&')
Out[22]: {'match': ['Z-300']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match = re.search('&match=(.*?)&', text).group(1)
```